# Memory consumption differences

Tags: c#, memory, garbage-collection

Some of our processes (.net managed) consumes different amount of memory on different systems.
one of the systems has 32 cores while the other has only 2 cores - can that fact impact the memory ?
I also noticed that there are many (20+) GC threads at the one that consume more while the other system doesn't.

Can that be related to the GC operational mode ?

Comment: it can - but what is the problem/goal?

Comment: Add more description for the problem we can not read your mind.

Comment: Ok , we have a generic process which hosts wcf services, in one of our strong system (32 cores + 32 giga RAM) this process uses 1G virtual size from starting point , while running at weaker system the process uses about 300M virtual size.

Comment: @Itay Is that reported by task manager? It isn't a good indicator of the memory a process is actually using, just an indicator of the memory the process was given. You might find the OS on the larger machine is more generous with working set because it has lots of spare memory capacity.

Comment: No, i watched the virtual size using Process explorer and Perfmon.

Comment: So the bigger box can serve more concurrent requests than the weaker box. More concurrent requests equals more threads equals more memory usage.